Why God sometimes does not help us sort out our problem even after we pray to him?
Let me explain the situation here. My wife's father was a really nice and a humble soul. He always used to help people with money, built their homes and used to donate a lot. He used to pray a lot every single day. However, he was very sick for a while. He had a kidney stone issue and he was not mentally strong that doctors could do surgery and remove the stone. At last he had a really painful death. He was in extreme pain due to kidney stone and his whole body got infected and he died due to multiple organs failure. My wife and I used to pray a lot. Specially, my wife who hardly used to sleep during her dad's last few days in the hospital as she was always praying. We had a long 20 hours flight when we were going back to meet my wife's dad and she never stopped praying. Her dad's death has made her lost faith in God. She believed that her dad did a good karma but still died a painful death which he never deserved. Moreover, she believed that God could have answered her prayers and could have given some more time so that she could have at least talked to him before he died. Her dad was unconscious when we reached hospital after travelling and later died in the hospital only.
I do believe that there could be a past karma which led to such a painful death. My wife's dad good karma in this life might have helped him attain moksha and clean his past life's sins. I guess God knows better than us as he is the creator of this whole universe and life.
However, even after praying and asking God for some sympathy was not answered. My wife believed that God could have given little bit more time at least or could have given an easy death to her dad. What could have been the reason that prayers were not answered?
I am so confused and I am hoping for someone to show me the right path.

My condolences. Even Bhishma-deva who was one of the noblest of souls in the Mahabharata had to endure the pain of lying on a bed of arrows at the end of his life even with Lord Krishna being near him. Small karmas can be reversed through prayers while others are irreversible as they're for the ultimate benefit / liberation of the soul which has taken many millions of incarnations. Om Shanti.

Surrender yourself to Hari and become his and then do naam jap and submit it to Hari and then pray if it is ok for lord he will do it and if it gets you far from Hari he will never  fulfill it.

The answer is karma. Every action has a result. Your wife's father's body at the end of his life was the result of earlier actions. He unfortunately had to face them and bravely lived through the results (thus undoing future results or phala where applicable). He also performed good actions, and the results will prevail. This lies with God.
Your prayer was also good in intention, and well spent. To wish others well is satvic and the result will be satvic. Results are inevitable even if not seen immediately or materially. Their effect on your wife's father is now outside of the material realm, leave that be. Their result with God and your future will inevitably bare satvic results.
To persist the goodness and satvic actions which you performed, you should now not concern one's thoughs on results past or future. One should trust in God. When the doubt or worry arises give it to God; surrender the results.
